# Node js variable holds data from previous call after being assigned valid data

Tags: android, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, android-volley

EDIT: The problem was with the validator.trim() function. Once I removed the trim function the code worked as it should.

This problem is hard for me to explain. I am running a node server with a mongodb(mongoose integration) and android requests made through volley.

The gist is sometimes when I send a request for say a registration module, with basic info (email, password, name), the variable assigned from the request body will change to the data of a previous request. So the data is there and correct from the post parameters, I just can't assign data from it to a new variable.If i do this it, the new variable will hold the value of the 'number' from the verification module below.

```
Ex.
...
var user_email = req.body.email;
...
console.log(user_email); // 7145557777
console.log(req.body.email);//test@email.com
```

EDIT:

The variable is random regardless of the scope. What could be causing this? Restarting the server temporarily fixes the issue, but after one registration call it happens again.

Defined in my routes as:

```
...
app.post('/register',function (req,res){
auth.register(req,res);
});
...
```

Registration Module

```
var register = function(req,res) {
    var user_email    = validator.trim(req.body.email);
    var user_password = validator.trim(req.body.pass);
    var user_last_name = validator.trim(req.body.lname);
    var user_first_name = validator.trim(req.body.fname);
    var user_major = validator.trim(req.body.major);
    var user_dob = validator.trim(req.body.dob);
    var user_rank = validator.trim(req.body.rank);
    var school_code = "";
    var school_name = "";

    console.log("email req " + req.body.email);
    console.log("email " + user_email);
    console.log("req ",req.body);

    if(user_email !== "" && user_password !== "" && user_last_name !== "" && user_first_name !== "")
    {
        models.Direc.findOne(
            {email_format:user_email.split('@')[1]},
            'school_code school_name',
            function (err, response) 
            {
                if(err)
                {
                    res.send("ERROR:Database");
                    return;
                }
                if(response != null)
                {
                    school_code = response.school_code;
                    school_name = response.school_name;
                }
                else
                {
                    res.send("school not found + " + user_email.split('@')[1]);
                    return;
                }
....
```

Other module used when verifying a phone number, called during previous registration.

```
    var verify_phone = function(req,res)
{
    var email = validator.trim(req.body.email);
    var access_token = validator.trim(req.body.access_token);
    var key_or_verify = validator.trim(req.body.key_or_verify);
    var number = validator = validator.trim(req.body.number);
    var key = validator = validator.trim(req.body.key);
    if(email != "" && access_token != "")
    {
        if(key_or_verify == "verify" && key.length < 6)
        {
            number = key.slice(5,key.length);
            models.User.findOneAndUpdate(
                {email:email, access_token:access_token,number_validate_key:key},
                {number:number,number_validate_key:""},
                {new:true},
                function (err,response)
                {
                    if(err)
                    {
                        res.send("ERROR:Database");
                        return;
                    }
                    try
                    {
                        if(response.number == number)
                        {
                            res.send("success");
                            return;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            res.send("not found");
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                    catch(e)
                    {
                        res.send("not found");
                        return;
                    }
                });
        }
        else if(key_or_verify == "key" && number.length > 0)
        {
            var key = Math.floor(Math.random()*99999) + 100000;
            key = key + number;

            models.User.findOneAndUpdate(
                {email:email, access_token:access_token},
                {number_validate_key:key},
                {new:true}, 
                function (err,response)
                {
                    if(err)
                    {
                        console.log(err);
                        res.send("ERROR:Database");
                        return;
                    }
                    try
                    {
                        if(response.number_validate_key == key)
                        {
                            res.send(JSON.stringify({
                                "key":key
                                }
                                ,null));
                            return;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            res.send("not found");
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                    catch(e)
                    {
                        res.send("not found");
                        return;
                    }
                }
            );
        }
        else
        {
            res.send("empty");
            return;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        res.send("empty");
        return;
    }
    return;
};
```

Comment: Caching? I know volley may cache "things" if the requests are always similar.

Comment: disabled caching, no change

Comment: I think we need more code context here. Also, do you have a loop or anything here? Where is `user_email` defined in relation to the `console.log()` statements?

Comment: @mscdex I posted more information. Also I recently disabled caching in my express headers.